# mapping with restkit " how to use multiple mapping and descriptor

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapping, restkit

Hello friends in stackoverflow:

I am having problem mapping data from the api using restkit.I really want to know where my mistake is.

Json format:

```
{
data: {
   -current_condition: [1]
       0:  {
           cloudcover: "16"
           humidity: "59"
          - weatherDesc: [1]
       0:  {
            value: "Clear"
          }

- weather: [5]
0:  {
    tempMinC: "10"
    tempMinF: "50"
    weatherCode: "119"
  -  weatherDesc: [1]
0:  {
     value: "Cloudy"
     }
    .......
}
```

here is my code how to do the mapping (I tried to mapping the 'cloudcover,humidity',and both 'weatherDesc' in current_condition and weather)

```
-(void)configureRestKit{

NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.raywenderlich.com"];
AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];

RKObjectManager *objectManager = [[RKObjectManager alloc] initWithHTTPClient:client];

RKObjectMapping *currentMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[CurrentCondition class]];
[currentMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"cloudcover",@"humidity",@"weatherDesc"]];
[currentMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"current_condition" toKeyPath:@"current_condition" withMapping:currentMapping]];


RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:currentMapping method:RKRequestMethodGET pathPattern:@"/demos/weather_sample/weather.php" keyPath:@"data.current_condition" statusCodes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:200]];

[objectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];



//weahter Desc
RKObjectMapping *weatherMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Weather class]];
[weatherMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"weatherDesc": @"myweatherDesc"}];
[weatherMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"weather" toKeyPath:@"weather" withMapping:weatherMapping]];

RKResponseDescriptor *weatherresponseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:weatherMapping method:RKRequestMethodGET pathPattern:@"/demos/weather_sample/weather.php" keyPath:@"data.weather" statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

[objectManager addResponseDescriptor:weatherresponseDescriptor];

}


-(void)loadCurrentCondition{

  NSDictionary *queryParams = @{@"format": @"json"};
  [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:@"/demos/weather_sample/weather.php"  parameters:queryParams success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
 _myArr = mappingResult.array;
 [self Humidity];
 } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
   NSLog(@"The error is :%@",error);
 }];

}

-(void)Humidity{
  restkitCurrentCondition *rkCC = [_myArr objectAtIndex:0];
  NSLog(@"///////////////////////the humidity is: %ld",rkCC.humidity.longValue);
  NSLog(@"//////////////////// the cloudcover is: %ld",rkCC.cloudcover.longValue);
  NSLog(@"/////////////// the weatherDesc is %@",rkCC.weatherDesc[0][@"value"]);
  NSLog(@"///////// the weatherDesc in weather is %@",rkCC.restkitweather.myweatherDesc[0][@"value"]);
  NSLog(@"///////// the weatherDesc in weather is %@",rkCC.restkitweather.myweatherDesc);
}
```

here is what I get:

```
2014-07-16 14:21:36.076 myRestSample[3783:60b] I restkit:RKLog.m:33 RestKit logging initialized...
2014-07-16 14:21:36.154 myRestSample[3783:60b] I 
restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:150 GET  
'http://www.raywenderlich.com/demos/weather_sample/weather.php?format=json'
2014-07-16 14:21:36.289 myRestSample[3783:3a0f] I 
restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:220 GET  
'http://www.raywenderlich.com/demos/weather_sample/weather.php?format=json' (200 OK / 6
 objects) [request=0.1323s mapping=0.0024s total=0.1525s]
 2014-07-16 14:21:36.289 myRestSample[3783:60b] -[Weather humidity]: unrecognized 
 selector sent to instance 0x8f8eb30
```

I tried to change the descritor's keypath to 'nil',looks like this

```
RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:currentMapping 
method:RKRequestMethodGET 
pathPattern:@"/demos/weather_sample/weather.php" keyPath:nil 
statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
```

The Weather and CurrentCondition are NSObject and there are four properties in CurrentCondition(cloudcover,humidity, NSArray *weaterDesc,Weather *restkitweather).There are only two properties in Weather.h (NSArray *myweatherDesc,*weatherDesc)

It seems I have already got 6 objects but why I got '[Weather humidity] Unreconized'.
Can anyone help??please..

Comment: What is the definition of your class `restkitCurrentCondition` (and note that class names should start with a capital letter)

Comment: Hey friend!Nice to meet you again.It is a NSObject and it has 4 properties in it (NSNumber *cloudcover,NSNumber *humidity,NSArray *weatherDesc,restKitWeather *restkiitweather)

Comment: @Wain I have already searched questions about restkit in overflow.You are the only person to give answers............Can you help me more?I have already update my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> '[Weather humidity] Unreconized'

This means that you have a `Weather` Instance, but you are treating it as a current conditions instance.

As per my answer to your other question you should not be using `_myArr = mappingResult.array;` because you can't be sure what the array contains. Instead you should be using the `dictionary` and extracting the correct type of object for your needs based on the key path.

Comment: You are awesome.your answer is correct.The problem is from _myArr and I have already fixed it.